# Xamarin facebook fork of proguard unable to acces .jar

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, apk, proguard

I'm using xamarin for android, and I wanted to build my app with proguard.

So I use one https://libraries.io/nuget/name.atsushieno.proguard.facebook

after I installed it and build my app, I always have this error:

```
Error Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\samih pc\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\App Name
\packages\name.atsushieno.proguard.facebook.5.3.2.2\build\..lib\proguard.jar    
App Name    C:\Users\samih pc\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\App Name\App Name\PROGUARD
```

I search online and I use the mklink /j , but I still got this error no matter what.

How can i fix that?

Do i need to change the proguard path to with the path of the mklink?

Comment: Hello Sam, any solution yet? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Sorry, but no, i didn't found a solution on how to use that proguard fork.

Comment: @French_FitGirl did you find any solution now?

Comment: sorry, i didn't found a solution.

Comment: The error seems to be in the path.  I suspect it should be \packages\name.atsushieno.proguard.facebook.5.3.2.2\build\..\lib\proguard.jar     OR  \packages\name.atsushieno.proguard.facebook.5.3.2.2\lib\proguard.jar .  However, I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @DavidLMorris maybe but i don't know why there are so much issues with proguard on xamarin...

Comment: My (non) solution was to turn off progard (and turn off linking) and wait for a resolution.  My comment above was because the path called seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and I found a fix to my problem. I had to update all my Xamarin.Android.Support.* nuget packages to the latest version. I have also updated the latest build tools.